# Find a word in a List

Tags: c#, list, filereader

I need to find a work in a List i made, the file im using as a test.txt has one line that says "This is a test" which is all read into one element in the list, I want the program to find if the word 'test' is in the list and if so change it to a capital.. Here is my code for reading everything in

```
string line;
        var list = new List<string>();
        var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\location\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
               list.Add(line);
           }
           //These are a few tries i made, none of them are doing the job tho
           //bool inlist = list.Contains("test");
           //var value = list.Find(item => item.name == "test").value;
           //var results = Array.FindAll(lines, s => s.Equals("test"));
```

Comment: Would you like to resave the capitalized word in the file?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman: good question but that is not what the OP is asking to do and would invite multiple questions into a single post (which is not the intent on StackOverflow).

Comment: What's the problem you are having? The only hint we have is this: "// Tried a few things here to get to work and all has failed". Note that this site doesn't like "questions" that are: "Here's my requirements. Make it work, thanks", we need to see what you've tried and where it's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, main thing is being able to find the word 'test' so i can make a streamwriter and fix it.  So far i been unable to find the keyword

Comment: Okay let me make a edit to my question, give me couple of min

Comment: OKay i added a few things i tried

Comment: Can your request be summarized as "Make all `test` in the file start with uppercase"? Do you have to update the file as well?

Comment: File does not have to be updated, this is apart of a larger project im working on, so far my project is able to record keystrokes in a log file in real time, i want to search that log file for a word and if that word is found open a message box to show user (in this case my friend who cant spell my name to save his life) to fix it.. Im just doing it for fun but having real problems finding the word i need

Answer (score 1):

Try using *Linq* and *Regular expressions* (to extract `test` as a *whole word*, not a *part of word*, e.g. *contestant*):

```
   var list = File
     .ReadLines(@"c:\location\test.txt")
     .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "\btest\b", "TEST"))
     .ToList(); // If you want List materialization
```

If you want to rename `test` in the 1st line only:

```
   var list = File
     .ReadLines(@"c:\location\test.txt")
     .Select((line, index) => index == 0 
        ? Regex.Replace(line, "\btest\b", "TEST")
        : line)
     .ToList(); // If you want List materialization
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. You can do much more with a `Regex` (regular expression) but this will directly answer your question:

```
var lines = new List<string>();

using(var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\location\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8) {
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) {
        lines.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());
    }
}

lines[0].Replace("test", "Test");
```

To generalize a function you can do something like this:

```
void FindAndReplace(List<string> lines, string toFind, string toReplace) {
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count ; i++) {
        lines[i] = Regex.Replace(lines[i], $"\b{toFind}\b", toReplace);
    }
}
```

Comment: More accurate implementation (in the generalization) is `{Regex.Escape(toFind)}` (what if I want to replace `"*"` to `"+"`)

Comment: What to do with the string returned from `Regex.Replace` :)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: the OP needs a launching point to learn. If requirements expand, let the OP investigate and learn.